# How can I change permanently env variable in cypress.json?

Tags: cypress

I have sundry spec.js files to run.
To increase tests performance and speed, I' ve created a first test file that login into my web service and store the token into an env variable called TOKEN that I' ve declared in cypress.json

```
{
  "env": {
      "TOKEN": ""
 },
  "viewportWidth": 1920,
  "viewportHeight": 1080,
  "responseTimeout": 90000,
  "defaultCommandTimeout": 60000,
  "requestTimeout": 60000
}
```

To do this I write the following code into the first test file:

```
describe('Setup', () => {

    it('Should setup token', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'path/to/endpoint', 
            headers: {
                'api_version': Cypress.env('API_VERSION')
            },
            body: { 
                userName: Cypress.env('USERNAME'), 
                password: Cypress.env('PASSWORD')
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            Cypress.config('TOKEN', response.body.token)
        });
    });
});
```

The POST call works and it return and save the TOKEN in the cypress.json but It is available only for the first test file, when I go ahead with other test files (according to the documentation) the stored token value is deleted, because the `Cypress.config('VAR_NAME', var_value)` works only on the test file that has used the statement.

I' ve tried to store the token value into a cookie and save permanently the cookie but the token is too long and cannot be stored into the cookie.

Is there a way to save the token into the cypress.json env PERMANENTLY?

Comment: I mean the idea is that the test files shoud be indepedent of each other. You want to couple all your test files to the login test file, but how can you guarantee it always runs first? Wouldn't it be a better idea to do a login before each test file? Or maybe you could store the token in the browser's local storage and tell cypress not to clear it between tests, but then there's still a problem with the run order.

Comment: The order is followed, the problem is that the cypress envirroment variable, is cleared each test file and I cannot use it for the other tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest way to overcome the "only current spec" problem is to run your request in a `before()` in `/cypress/support/index.js`

```js
// support/index.js

before(() => {
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'path/to/endpoint', 
    ...
  }).then((response) => {
    Cypress.config('TOKEN', response.body.token) 
  });
})
```

When I run a couple of simple validation tests

```js
// support/index.js
Cypress.config('test', 'test1')
```

```js
// tests 1 & 2
it('sees globally set config', () => {
  expect(Cypress.config('test')).to.eq('test1')
})
```

it passes

```js
       Spec                                              Tests  Passing  Failing  Pending  Skipped  
  ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
  │ √  config1.spec.js                           89ms        1        1        -        -        - │
  ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
  │ √  config2.spec.js                          136ms        1        1        -        -        - │
  └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
    √  All specs passed!                        225ms        2        2        -        -        -
```